Render HTML to pdf and append images
I'm writing a python script that can read html from stdin and render it to a file (with css, though my example code omits that), along with attaching any trailing image paths on the command. Using the fpdf2 documentation I wrote a script that depends on pdfkit (and wkhtmltopdf), fpdf, and pdfrw:
# Usage:
# cat test.html | python3 script.py out.pdf img1.png img2.jpg

from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from fpdf import FPDF
import pdfkit
import sys

OUTPUT_FILE = sys.argv[1]

pdfkit.from_string("".join(sys.stdin.readlines()), OUTPUT_FILE)
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in PdfReader(OUTPUT_FILE).pages:
    writer.addpage(page)

for path in sys.argv[2:]:
    fpdf = FPDF()
    fpdf.add_page()
    fpdf.image(path)
    reader = PdfReader(fdata=bytes(fpdf.output()))
    writer.addpage(reader.pages[0])

writer.write(OUTPUT_FILE)

It works! The problem—it's writing to OUTPUT_FILE, creating an empty PdfWriter, opening OUTPUT_FILE, appending it to the writer, and writing OUTPUT_FILE again. I've tried a few approaches but they always omit first page of rendered html:

Storing the rendered html and importing that into the writer:
pdf = pdfkit.from_string("".join(sys.stdin.readlines()))
writer = PdfWriter(trailer=PdfReader(fdata=pdf))


Writing the rendered html pdf and opening it directly with the writer:
pdfkit.from_string("".join(sys.stdin.readlines()), output_filename)
writer = PdfWriter(trailer=PdfReader(output_filename))



Any ideas how I can tweak this to manipulate the pdf in memory and only write to disk once?

@KJ That's a good idea! I might be able to get something with stringio... will attempt in the morning

@KJ  True! I'd use io.BytesIO instead of io.StringIO
